# SQL between and including

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an problem here i cant seem to figure out with a god solution.

I have a mysql table with a column containing sku for my products.

- G67909
- G78960
- G81990
- G81772
- G88098
- G90099
- G93000
- G99128
- G192012

I want to return everything between and including G8 and G9.

I use this command:
`SELECT id, sku FROM table WHERE sku BETWEEN 'G8%' AND 'G9%'`

This command will only return those staring with G8xxxx and not G9xxxx.

Is there an easy way to include sku's starting with G9?

Comment: Use 2 like statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use regular expressions:

```
SELECT id, sku
FROM table 
WHERE sku REGEXP '^G[89]';
```

Answer (score 0):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c981fea/2

```
SELECT id, sku 
FROM `table` 
WHERE sku LIKE 'G%' 
AND substring(sku,2,1) between 8 and 9;
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL Fiddle to test http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/3dd2c2/2

```
SELECT id, sku
FROM table 
WHERE sku like 'G8%' or sku LIKE 'G9%';
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer by editing it, such that others can learn from it